# How do I detect unused collections in SonarQube?

Tags: intellij-idea, collections, sonarqube

We've found a bug in our code that I can't seem to find a SonarQube rule for. I think it's an interesting one because IntelliJ's analysis will display a very helpful message:

> **Contents of collection 'XXXX' are updated, but never queried**
>
> Reports collection fields or variables whose contents are either queried and
>   not updated, or updated and not queried. Such mismatched queries and
>   updates are pointless, and may indicate either dead code or a
>   typographical error.

The warning identifier seems to be `MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfCollection`.

Is there any analogous warning in SonarQube?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it in the `fb-contrib` plugin:

`fb-contrib:WOC_WRITE_ONLY_COLLECTION_FIELD`